# Why did Voyager have to shunt unused electrical power and radiate as heat?

Tags: voyager, rtg, radiators

Reading about Voyager in [The oldest computer (not) on Earth](https://www.muckrock.com/news/archives/2016/oct/03/one-governments-oldest-computers-isnt-earth/) I saw the image below, where is shown a *science instrument calibration panel and shunt radiator*.

According to the November 1980 NASA News Release [Voyager Backgrounder](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19810001583.pdf):

> A .36-square-m (4-square-ft.) shunt radiator/science calibration target faces outward from the propulsion module truss adapter toward the scan platform. The dual-purpose structure is a flat sandwich of two aluminum radiating surfaces lining a honeycomb core. Through power collectors and emitter resistors between the plates, **any amount of the electrical power from the radioisotope thermoelectric generators can be radiated to space as heat.** The outer surface also serves as a photometric calibration target for the remote-sensing science instruments on the
>   scan platform.

Why would it be necessary to build a system to radiate unused electrical power as heat? According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator#Space) each of Voyager's three [MHW-RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHW-RTG)s started with 2400 W of thermal power producing only 160W of electrical power. I assume that using or shunting the 160W of electrical power results in 160W less radiated power, but why was providing a maximum 7% drop in radiated power worth adding the weight and complexity of this electrical and radiation system?

[image]

Comment: just fyi solar panels have shunts for unused power [When there is more power than needed, are satellite photovoltaics shunted or open circuit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17516/12102)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not about reducing radiated power. The shunt is used to keep the bus voltage constant when the power draw changes.

A similar system was used on [Cassini](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/11180/):

> Other portions of the power system include the power control boards, with 192 solid-state power switches (SSPSs), a radiator to “shunt” excess, unused power as heat to space, and a shunt regulator assembly, which (1) tells the radiator how much power to shunt and (2) maintains the spacecraft bus voltage at 30 volts.

It's done this way because [a shunt is simple](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-851-satellite-engineering-fall-2003/lecture-notes/l3_scpowersys_dm_done2.pdf): it's just a switch that diverts power to the shunt resistor. The alternative is the use of an [electronic system that regulates bus voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter). In this alternative, all input power is routed through electronic components, and you get a higher component count an some losses.

> Direct Energy Transfer (DET) systems dissipates unneeded power
>   – Typically use shunt resistors to maintain bus voltage at a predetermined level
>
> Peak Power Trackers (PPT) extract the exact power required from the solar array
>   – Uses DC to DC converter in series with the array
>   – Requires 4 - 7% of the solar array power to operate

Comment: I meant "high-power electronics that convert one voltage to another" as opposed to switches that switch the output of a thermocouple to the shunt resistor.