# What happened to DSCOVR, what stopped working?

Tags: dscovr

In Scott Manley's recent video [Views Of Earth and the Seasons From A Million Miles Away - DSCOVR & EPIC](https://youtu.be/xPM2kITNtTs?t=264) after about `04:20` he says:

> …it’s one of my favorite missions because it has this very simple idea of just showing the Earth continuously. So you could browse to a web page and always see what it was, until June (2019) when it stopped working; we haven’t had any updates since then.

**Question:** What stopped working, the EPIC camera or the whole DSCOVR payload or the whole satellite, bus and all? There are [a lot of instruments](http://spaceflight101.com/dscovr/) on DSCOVR, including some that provide early warning of major solar events that could disrupt Earth satellites and power distribution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99298/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-what-happened-to-dscovr-what-stopped-working).

Comment: EPIC pictures started being mad available again on the 12th February, with daily pictures resuming on the 20th

Comment: @JCRM Thanks! That could also potentially be a helpful edit to the current answer or a new answer.

Comment: it's a pointer that there might be more information available, but doesn't, in itself, add any useful information.

Comment: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/03/03/space_roundup/

Comment: @JCRM thanks! I've [left a note](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39120/what-happened-to-dscovr-what-stopped-working?noredirect=1#comment136857_39129) below the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On June 27th, 2019 NASA states that DSCOVR is in a "safe-hold".

> All DSCOVR space weather instrument data and other instrument data have been suspended as the spacecraft has entered into safe-hold. Anomaly investigations and associated recovery activities are underway.

[Source: NASA](https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/news/dscovr-spacecraft-has-entered-safe-hold)

A few days later they said it had to do with the satellite's position.

> “NOAA is addressing a performance issue with the DSCOVR satellite,” John Leslie, a spokesperson for NOAA, told Popular Science in a statement. “Engineers have placed the satellite into a ‘safehold’ position, while they first diagnose and then work to fix a technical issue in the system that maintains the satellite’s position.”

[Source: MSN](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/our-best-defense-against-space-weather-has-been-offline-for-weeks/ar-AAEmeao#page=2)

[According to Simon Carn](https://twitter.com/simoncarn/status/1175823150984126464), the September DSCOVR Science Team meeting reports...

> they hope to restore EPIC by January 2020. Need to implement star-tracking software to replace faulty gyro, so the S/C can orient itself & point accurately at Earth.

Comment: What stopped working?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't find any more information.

Comment: Source with no citations, vague clues, July 17: https://www.planetxnews.org/our-best-defense-against-space-weather-has-been-offline-for-weeks-why/

Comment: @bitchaser Thanks, I found a better source. Still a mystery.

Comment: based on [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39120/what-happened-to-dscovr-what-stopped-working/39129#comment126309_39120) above I searched "DSCOVR gyro" and found [this item](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=37745.40) which includes a link to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/simoncarn/status/1175823150984126464). If you like you can update your answer with these.

Comment: @uhoh Done, thanks.

Comment: looks great, thanks!

Comment: Another "source" but less information and not much greater credibility - https://spacenews.com/software-fix-planned-to-restore-dscovr/

Comment: I think there has been some more recent news:  Wikipedia says [DSCOVR came out of the safe hold on March 2, 2020, and resumed normal operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory#Operation) and links to Space News' [DSCOVR back in operation](https://spacenews.com/dscovr-back-in-operation/) yay!

Comment: That's a really bad wikipedia entry :(